# Why I can't use '@' symbol in Prisma MySQL full text search?

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping, prisma

I've written a simple text search query with the Prisma client to search Usernames or emails in my users table. While it correctly works with usernames, it errors out saying, `Unexpected '@'`.I believe that's due to @ is a special symbol.Is there anyway around this, because I need to be able to search full email addresses. (Emails are correctly saved in the database). And query return results if I omit the part from @.Ex: in abc@gmail.com, query returns match if I just search abc.But If I use abc@gmail.com, it fails with this error.

```
 Error occurred during query execution:
 ConnectorError(
  ConnectorError { 
   user_facing_error: None, 
   kind: QueryError(Server(ServerError { 
                           code: 1064, message: "syntax error, 
                           unexpected '@',expecting $end", state: "42000" }
)) })
```

How do I solve this, I searched the documentation, but I couldn't find anything related to this.
My User model looks like this,

```
model User {
  id              Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  username        String  @db.VarChar(255)
  email           String  @db.VarChar(255)
  avatar          String? @db.VarChar(255)
  password        String  @default("1") @db.VarChar(255)
  friends         User[]  @relation("friends")
  friendsRelation User[]  @relation("friends")
  hashRT          String? @db.VarChar(255)

  @@fulltext([username])
  @@fulltext([email])
  @@fulltext([username, email])
  @@map("users")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a late answer but if you still had the same error this might help I fixed this error by replacing search with contains like this

```
prisma.user.findMany({where:{email:{contains:"email@email.com"}}})
```